# Need for a microservice framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, microservices

I am trying to understand the motivation of using a `'framework'` for microservices,  through any reference literature or paper.
Assume that we have defined/designed  the segregation of responsibilities well into independent java processes with their own data stores.
Each of these processes can publish and consume from an event bus, and are capable of being orchestrated/choreographed through well-defined events.
Why would I then need a spring boot or any other framework - instead of simply spawning multiple instances of these standalone java processes.
Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

A framework is to make the development process easier and quicker. You can of course go and write your standalone microservices without using any framework while using an event bus/queue to communicate across microservices. But this might be time taking as you may need to write lots of thing from scratch. Frameworks like spring boot(Java) or Expressjs(node.js) provide a minimal configuration interface and set of APIs that can be used to develop microservices rather quickly than without using a framework.

Comment: Is there a brief oh what exactly those specific value-adds that spring-boot brings  - that would otherwise be needed to be written by the developer to make his java process a microservice.Most of literature are just plain tutorials

Comment: For that, I would suggest, just go and implement a basic CRUD REST application with spring boot and without it. That might help you understand the features of spring boot

Comment: There are lot of benefits, just a few of them that typically apply esp. for spring _ecosystem_:
- Battle-tested solution - it runs in prod in a lot of projects
- Community + great documentation - you'll find answer to any question you come across, also if there is something new the support will be provided shortly due to active development
- Easy to start off - as @Anant suggested, compare to custom approach and you'll feel the difference
- Easy to find new developers on the market and build a team that would bring value  shortly

Answer (score 0):

Using an established framework such as Springboot or .NET Core etc., enables any dev teams to deliver, better, faster, and better.

Spring Boot is an efficient framework for creating a Spring-based application. Using a well-established framework leads toward a small learning curve, yet it can be used to create robust production-grade applications. Spring Boot provides many built-in tools and frameworks that make developing a cloud-based microservice rather easy.

Also, when it comes to picking a technology, I would always recommend the one which has great community support and has proven credibility in the industry.

Hence, if you decide yo go raw and begin your journey, there is no doubt that you will be successful, and I agree there might be a lot of learnings on the way, but I am not sure if ROI will be of that worth. Technology is to make us move faster, and take some pain away from daily development, which then allows devs and architects to stay focused on the design-n-architecture of the application.

Answer (score -1):

SpringBoot provides production ready web applications. Springboot comes up with AutoConfiguration and embedded servers. It reduces lots of boiler plate . Lots of services  of spring like spring jpa , spring security, spring cloud, spring aop as well non spring services like hibernate, mongo-db, kafka, oracle/mysql, oauth2, etc can be integrated easily. Microservices architecture eureka client, api-gateway, zipkin,zuul,config-server,service-discovery can be configured in springboot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).